# Proving bases of representation for a specific base, image question part D. (please give hint, no answer)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

[image: cemc problem of the month]

I recently went on CEMC waterloo's website and stumbled across this question. Part a, b and c were pretty easy and using the fact from part c, the two facts in part d can be proven. But I am stuck on knowing how those two facts would help me to prove the original question in d, which is that every positive integer has a base $\phi$ representation. Maybe the two facts imply directly that every real number has a base $\phi$ representation and positive integers are a subset of real numbers, so it's already proven? I am very stuck on how to use the two facts, and I don't want answers but just hints. I need hints on how to incorporate the two facts into my proof. This is a grade 12 level math contest question, so I would assume not too many advanced number theory techniques would be involved in doing this. However, looking at this, I am thinking base of representation theorem, but I still have no luck approaching it. If anyone can give me one hint, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\phi^{n+2}=\phi^{n+1}+\phi^n$ means that in base-$\phi$, $100_\phi=011_\phi$.

Assume that we know the base-$\phi$ represenation of $n$. Then the base-$\phi$ represenation of $n+1$ is just adding $1$ on $d_0$. But, what if already $d_0=1$? Can we shift down $d_0$ using the fact above?

Comment: thanks so much. That helped a lot.